# Entity Framework Generating DbSet instead of single class

Tags: entity-framework

I have a tiny database with one tiny Table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Connections](
        [connectionID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ipAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [ConnectionGUID] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [created] [datetime] NULL,
        [registrationID] [varchar](100) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Connections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [connectionID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I generate the model from the database, it generates:

```
public virtual DbSet<Connections> Connections { get; set; }
```

of which:

```
public partial class Connections
    {
        public long connectionID { get; set; }
        public string ipAddress { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionGUID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created { get; set; }
        public string registrationID { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't know why it generated the DbSet instead of the single class

When I am trying to fill the class and SaveChanges, how do I access the DbSet?

```
using (savitassaEntities3 entities3 = new savitassaEntities3())
            {
                entities3.Connections conn = new Connections();

            }
```

It's also colliding with the SignalR class Connections as this is aSignalR Hub.

Comment: This is basic EF behavior. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc or http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4 . As for the namespace collision -- use the full namespace for both `Connections` classes i.e. `new entities3.Connections()`.

Comment: yep that's how EF works. Your class is Connection, your DbSet (wrapper for EF bridging your class & your database) is simply a property of entities (context) I'd recommend making that singular, BTW, then your namespace problem goes away and the class name is more logical).

Comment: p.s. if you are confused about "what is this dbset", not "why the namespace collision" go watch at least module 5 (interacting with your ef model) of my EF5 course on Pluralsight. IIRC you have a subscription. :)

Comment: You're the expert but I looked at all my EF code I've written in my projects here and all of them generated a *single* class, not a DbSet. I just new'd the class and filled in and then SaveChanges. Here I only have access to the DbSet with no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a database perspective, think of the DbSet as the Table and the class (Connections) as a row in that table. The DbSet is included in a DbContext class which you can think of as your Database.

As for the name collision with Connections, make sure to fully namespace qualify it. `entities3.Connections conn = new MyProject.MyNamespace.Connections();`

Thus to select records, you would do something along the lines of

```
var cn = new savitassaEntities3();
var query = cn.Connections.Where(c => c.foo == bar);
```

To insert a connection, use

```
cn.Connections.Add(value);
cn.SaveChanges();
```

If I'm missing what you're trying to do and what you have, feel free to add some more code and I can take a look.

Comment: But I am used to just filling a class and SaveChanges(). Can you show me the code to do this?

Comment: You're not filling A dbset. You are using a dbset as a tool to retrieve data from the database and materialize classes. For example, if you want one particular collection whose id value is 47: entities3.collections.find(47) will return a collection class instance for that particular one. Again, I recommend renaming the class to a singular so it's logical and distinguishable from the dbset,

Comment: But there is nothing in the database. I just want to put something in.

Comment: Well then use Jim's edited exampl for using add and the savechanges. You should really go watch that course module. Inserting data is a very basic feature. And if you already watched it, I know how it is sometimes when you need to see something when you are u sing it rather than learning a ton and storing it away.

Comment: I got it now - got confused